# slow postgres performance with simple querys

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-performance, performance-tuning

after alot of reading i found multiple sources saying postgres should be able to handle ~100 million rows

i set up a simple table with:

```
CREATE TABLE trade
(
    id INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    symbol VARCHAR(),
    open_time TIMESTAMP,
    end_price INT
)
```

i have 12 million of thies records

my simple query of

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE symbol=x and open_time>start_time and open_time<end_time
```

this query always returns less than a 1000 rows yet it take 1100 millisecond this seams like alot for a simple table with 10x less rows than it should handle?

altho i dont have any indexes cause i dont know what would be the best indexs to put on this table.

is it possible to get this down to 100ms?

any help writing a more performant query or db would be appriciated

EDIT 1:

after reading the comments i put the following indexes on the table

```
CREATE INDEX open_time ON trade(open_time);
CREATE INDEX symbol ON trade(symbol);
CREATE INDEX end_price ON trade(open_price);
```

after adding this the query time is 240 ms is this the max?

altho i have noteced
querying the beginging 40k rows the query time drops to 60ms
after that is rises to 240ms what is causing this?

Comment: Without any indexes all 12 million rows must be read every time, so 1 second response time is actually pretty good. Postgres documentation has a chapter dedicated to explaining how indexes work and how to choose a good one for your workload; did you have a chance to read it?

Comment: Yes, Postgres can easily work with tables in size of gigabytes it all depends on what your hardware is and if you can predict the queries, Even simple queries will quickly grow in CPU and IO cost if you have to make a full table scan to sort them and even to order them If you are going to work with tables of that size you will need indexes for them to work under load.

Comment: @mustaccio i do have time, i looked online for index info but came up short. if you could link it that would be amzing

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-intro.html

Comment: Several single column indexes are usually not the best idea. For your query the index (symbol, open_time) probably works better, but you should look at all of your queries to find the best set of indexes

Comment: You have a lot to learn, https://use-the-index-luke.com/ is probably a decent place to start (including the bit on concatenated indexes). A well designed table with well designed indexes will give you very quick sensible queries no matter how many rows are in a table. Going through execution plans is probably a good idea if you're struggling to appreciate why somethings take some time - the data you've stored must be found somehow!

Comment: @Lennart i used your index in the mean time of reading the link andrew put, it had amazing results of 30ms querys but after running it for a while it went back up to 200 ms? is fluctuations like this normal

Comment: Not an expert in postgres but, did you run a lot of other queries in the meantime?

Answer (score 0):

The perfect index for this query is a two-column index, with the column that is compared with `=` first:

```
CREATE INDEX ON trade (symbol, open_time);
```

If that is still slow, the `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` output for the query should tell us why.